# How to stop TextView from stretching in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have a vertical LinearLayout and TextView.

File: unitdetails.xml

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/unit_details_person"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/unit_person_header"
  android:orientation="vertical" />
```

File: person_phone.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Some text">
</TextView>
```

I add TextView in my Activity code

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Person person = iterator.next();

            TextView positionTV = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.person_position, null);
            TextView personTV = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.person_person, null);
            TextView phoneTV = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.person_phone, null);
            TextView emailTV = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.person_email, null);

            positionTV.setText(person.getPosition());
            personTV.setText(person.getPerson());
            phoneTV.setText(person.getPhone());
            emailTV.setText(person.getEmail());

            Linkify.addLinks(phoneTV, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
            Linkify.addLinks(emailTV, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);

            personLinearLayout.addView(positionTV);
            personLinearLayout.addView(personTV);
            personLinearLayout.addView(phoneTV);
            personLinearLayout.addView(emailTV);
        }
```

After adding, TextView is extend whole screen width and system start dialer when I click on the right side of phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set the params programmatically like this:

```
myTextView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and remove the

```
android:layout_weight="0"
```

Which is useless here?

Comment: Or, instead of using `addView(View child)` use `addView(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)` and specify layout params as suggested.